# How can i test abstract android fragment by instrumental test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-fragments, mockito

I have a task to test abstract-fragment https://github.com/Mobile-Connect/android_sdk_v3/blob/develop/Application/src/main/java/com/gsma/mobileconnect/r2/android/demo/fragments/BaseAuthFragment.java by instrumental tests. And I quite don't understand how to do it right.

I've read some tutorial, but it's the only basement.. so, now I have a few thinks about:

1. 1) I should use **ActivityTestRule** because I need an activity to
   add my fragment to that.
2. 2) my class (fragment) is abstract, so to
       communicate with this I inherit my test-class from it, and then i
       create an instance of me test-class to work with fragment's methods.

so, now i have structure like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class BaseAuthFragment_ExampleTest extends BaseAuthFragment{

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DiscoveryResponse discoveryResponse) {}

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
    private MainActivity mainActivity = null;
    BaseAuthFragment fragment = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        //MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mainActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
    }

    @After
    public void setDown() {
        mainActivity = null;
        fragment = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(mainActivity);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragment = new BaseAuthFragment_ExampleTest();
        MobileConnectAndroidView as = BaseAuthFragment.mobileConnectAndroidView;
        fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            }
        });

        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();

        fragment.connectMobileDemo();
        MobileConnectAndroidView as2 = BaseAuthFragment.mobileConnectAndroidView;
        assertThat(as, is(as2));
    }
}
```

I want to explain my thinks on the example of first method (**connectMobileWithoutDiscovery**):

1. firstly there is set **mobileConnectConfig**, but it's protected.
   So there are 2 options, as for me:

   - just skip test of this
   - try to get the difference in this object before and after method's call using reflection. (maybe I even can try to mock returned values of
     methods like withClientSecret and withCacheResponsesWithSessionId and
     check that it was called with right parameters).
2. then we can see calling of **setupMobileConnect** method, but
   it's private too, and I don't know should I use some outer libraries
   like powermockito to check that it was called or should I just check
   before and after method's calling static field
   **mobileConnectAndroidView** which set in this method.

so, I just want to know I think in the right direction or not.

Comment: oh, sorry, and i have a restriction - i cannot mock my fragment under test.

Answer (score 1):

BaseAuthFragment is an *abstract* Fragment, and is clearly meant to be subclassed. It seems clear to me that a proper test would involve a subclass as you have done, but that subclass should probably be an *nested class* or *a sibling of the same package* rather than the test itself. This would give you some feedback on whether future changes to BaseAuthFragment require changes to subclasses, because you've created that testing subclass yourself.

Presumably your fragment-under-test could keep track of which methods have been called (which you might otherwise look to Mockito spying for), and expose getters for state that would otherwise be hidden, or that you expect subclasses to track, or that you would otherwise need to infer from method call order.

Also, by making a Fragment intended for testing (but that isn't your test), you can feel free to extend the visibility of limited-visibility methods (`protected`). That said, if you follow the practice of putting your tests in the same package as your class-under-test (possibly in a different source folder) you can still access those methods without changing visibility: `protected` is less-protected than the default package-private visibility level.